Integrate Gmail API to Android Kotlin app
I was trying to implement email sending functionality using Gmail API in a Kotlin Android application. I was able to implement Google one-tap sign-in. I'm getting the token from the onActivityResult() function. I want to use this token to access Gmail API and send an email.
This is my source code that I used to implement Google one-tap sign-in. I want to implement the email sending functionality with the Gmail API. Can you kindly help me regarding this problem.
val SERVER_CLIENT_ID ="#######################.apps.googleusercontent.com"
private lateinit var oneTapClient: SignInClient
private lateinit var signInRequest: BeginSignInRequest
val REQ_ONE_TAP = 100

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
        val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
        insets
    }

    // get reference to button
    var authBtn = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button) as Button
    authBtn.setOnClickListener(){
        oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)
        signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setPasswordRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(true)
                .build())
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                    .setServerClientId(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
                    // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                    .build())
            // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
            .build()

        oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this) { result ->
                try {

                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                        result.pendingIntent.intentSender, REQ_ONE_TAP,
                        null, 0, 0, 0, null)
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.localizedMessage}")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
                // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                Log.d(TAG, e.localizedMessage)
            }
    }

}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun generateSecureNonce(length: Int = 32): String? {
    val random = SecureRandom()
    val nonceBytes = ByteArray(length)
    random.nextBytes(nonceBytes)
    return Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(nonceBytes)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val tv = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    when (requestCode) {
        REQ_ONE_TAP -> {
            try {
                val credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)
                val idToken = credential.googleIdToken
                val username = credential.id
                val password = credential.password
                when {
                    idToken != null -> {
                        // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                        // with your backend.
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got ID token.")
                        tv.setText(idToken.toString())
                    }
                    password != null -> {
                        // Got a saved username and password. Use them to authenticate
                        // with your backend.
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got password.")
                    }
                    else -> {
                        // Shouldn't happen.
                        Log.d(TAG, "No ID token or password!")
                        tv.setText("No ID or Password")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                tv.setText(e.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}


signin gives you an authencation token or an id token.    What you need is authorization and an access token.  This is two different systems.    There is a Java quickstart but nothing for kotlin
